# Computing the Log-Euclidean distance efficiently by using eigen-analysis.

Tags: metric-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, logarithms, computational-complexity

Let $A,B\in\Bbb{S}_{++}^n$ be two symmetric positive definite $n\times n$ matrices with real entries. The Log-Euclidean distance between these matrices is defined as follows
$$
d = \lVert \log(A) - \log(B) \rVert_{F},
$$
where $\lVert\cdot\rVert_{F}$ denotes the Frobenius norm and $\log(\cdot)$ the principal logarithm.

I am interested in "simplifying" this formula, such that I can efficiently compute it in $\texttt{C}$ using probably some linear algebra library (such as the GNU Scientific Library - GSL).

What I have thought so far is to exploit:

**(a)** the definition of the Frobenius norm, that is
$$
\lVert A \rVert_{F} = \sqrt{ \operatorname{tr}(A^\top A) },
$$
and

**(b)** the fact that, by conducting eigen-analysis on $A$, $B$, i.e., by writing $A$, $B$ as 
$$
A = U_A\Lambda_AU_A^\top,\quad B = U_B\Lambda_BU_B^\top,
$$
the logarithms can be written as
$$
\log(A) = U_A \log(\Lambda_A) U_A^\top
= U_A \operatorname{diag}\big(\log(\lambda_A^1),\ldots,\log(\lambda_A^n)\big) U_A^\top,
$$
and
$$
\log(B) = U_B \log(\Lambda_A) U_B^\top,
= U_B \operatorname{diag}\big(\log(\lambda_B^1),\ldots,\log(\lambda_B^n)\big) U_B^\top.
$$

Let's assume that conducting eigen-analysis using GSL in $\texttt{C}$ is not computationally expensive, that is, $U_A$, $U_B$, $\Lambda_A$, and $\Lambda_B$ can be computed efficiently enough, then **what would be the best strategy for computing the Log-Euclidean distance?**

On the other hand, is there any other approach potentially more efficient that this using eigen-analysis?

Thank you very much!

Comment: How big is $n$ for you typically? Once you have computed the difference of the logs, the Frobenius norm is just the normal 2-norm on all the matrix elements, so don't compute it using the trace of a matrix product. I don't think there is any room to be clever here unless you know something about $U_A$ and $U_B$ (like that they are always the same).

Comment: $n$ could be equal or around $10^3$, for instance, but the norm should be computed for many pairs of $A$, $B$. Basically, that's the problem. In fact, we know nothing about $U_A$, $U_B$ a-priori. However, in some cases, $A$, $B$ are diagonal, then it's rather trivial. Many thanks for your response!

Comment: If you actually know nothing about the eigenstructure of $A$ and $B$, then you can't do any better than the straightforward implementation: compute the two eigendecompositions, perform the logs, reconstitute the products, take the difference, then compute the root-sum-of-squares norm. Attempting to exploit the orthogonal-invariance of the Frobenius norm doesn't gain any advantage here since it just shifts around when you do the matrix multiplications.